# Angular - How to change route to specific page and pass params, then execute function with params after route loaded?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a main page including two route pages (using ngRoute) `page1` and `page2` with separate child controllers. There is a search bar on the main page.

Assuming I'm on `page1` right now, By submitting the search bar form, I want to change the path to `page2` and pass the string as a param, then execute a function of `controller2` with the param passed in.

Below is my code, I'm using `$broadcast` to pass the param, but the function will not be executed unless I set a delay of 1000ms. My question is how can I change the route to page2 and trigger `$on` after route loaded ?

html(main page):

```
<div ng-controller="mainController">

 //form
 <form ng-submit="search()">
  <input type="text" ng-model="searchText"></input>
 <button type="submit">
 </form>

 //route
<div ng-view></div>

<div>
```

route:

```
     $routeProvider
        .when('/page1', {
            templateUrl: 'page1.html',
            controller: 'controller1',
        })
        .when('/page2', {
            templateUrl: 'page2.html',
            controller: 'controller2'
        })
```

main controller:

```
    $scope.search = function() {
        $location.path('/page2');
        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.$broadcast('search', $scope.searchText);
        }, 1)
    }
```

controller2:

```
    $scope.$on('search', function(event, data) {
      $scope.filterData(data)
    });
```

Comment: don't broadcast.  pass the parameter as part of the route change instead.  You should list your route configuration, since that is where the changes to your code would be made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the search text within the URL redirect:

```
$scope.search = function () {
    $location.path('/page2/').search({ search: $scope.searchText });
};
```

Then in your controller you can access the query string parameters through the $route service:

```
yourapp.controller('controller2', ['$scope', '$route', function ($scope, $route) {
    $scope.filterData($route.current.params.search);
}]);
```

You can also preload data in the route using resolve. This means the route waits for any promises to resolve before instantiating the controller, so when your controller does load, the data has already been fetched and can be filtered.

```
 $routeProvider
        .when('/page1', {
            templateUrl: 'page1.html',
            controller: 'controller1',
        })
        .when('/page2', {
            templateUrl: 'page2.html',
            controller: 'controller2',
            resolve: [function(){
                return $http....
            }]
        })
```

Ideally the resolve should call the same service the controller uses so that the data can be cached.

```
    resolve: ['SearchService', function(SearchService){
        return SearchService.fetchContent()
    }]
...
    yourapp.controller('controller2', ['$scope', '$route', 'SearchService', function ($scope, $route, SearchService) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `$broadcast`, you should use route parameters to pass information between routes.  One way to accomplish this could look like the following:

Routes:

```
.when('/page2/:search', {
...
}
```

Navigation:

```
//navigate to `/page2/search
$location.path('/page2/'+$scope.searchText);
```

In controller2:

```
controller('controller2', function($scope, $routeParams) {
  $scope.searchedText = $routeParams.search;
}
```

Full info and examples in the angular documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route).